# How to fix base_url() issue in CodeIgniter 3.1.0?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose, I have a project **inventory**, written by CodeIgniter. The problem I face is:

In CodeIgniter 3.1.0 the value return by `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` is http://[::1]/inventory/

but older version of CodeIgniter ( i.e: 3.0.1 ) returns the full base path ( i.e: http://localhost/inventory ).

Now, I want to return the full base path using `base_url()` in CodeIgniter 3.1.0 [ i.e:: http://localhost/inventory instead of http://[::1]/inventory/ ]

Can anyone tell me how can I do that in CodeIgniter 3.1.0?

Comment: did you change in `$config['base_url'] = '';` in config file?

Comment: what is your problem?? [::1] and localhost are basically the same thing.

Comment: @SayantanDas :: http: //localhost is more meaningful than [::1] for me ( maybe for others ), that's why I want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your base url in application/config/config.php

change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'something';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

No need to change anything after placing this .If u r using local or live host.

Answer (score 1):

open your `application/config` directory where you will find `config.php` file. Now `$config['base_url'] = '';` change this as following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/inventory/';
```

This is mandatory in Codeigniter 3.1.0